# How do I parse an integer in a Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

What is the equivalent of `parseInt()` (JS) or `intval()` (PHP) in Google Sheets?

I want to compute the sum of the numbers in a row in a separate cell. So if I had `3 cups` and `5 cups` in a row, I would get `18`.

Comment: Do you mean "3 cups" and "15 cups", or am I missing something?

Answer (score 19):

One way to implement something like this is

```
=VALUE(INDEX(FILTER(SPLIT(A1, " "), ISNUMBER(SPLIT(A1, " "))); 1; 1))
```

The result of this formula for some example strings is given below.

[image]

You may have to modify this to suit your individual needs.  It should work pretty well for strings as simple as "3 cups".

- `SPLIT(..., " ")` splits a string into its space-separated parts.  You can add more characters to the string, e.g. `" -/"`, to split whenever those characters are found.
- `ISNUMBER` checks if a string is a number.
- `FILTER` takes the array and filters out everything that doesn't satisfy the second function, i.e., it takes out everything that isn't a number.
- `INDEX(...; 1; 1)` returns the value in the first row, first column of the array (so we only get the first number listed, not all the numbers listed).
- `VALUE` probably won't be necessary, but just for good measure it converts the final string into a numeric value.

Comment: So the answer is `VALUE` ...

Comment: @IulianOnofrei No, `VALUE` raises an error ("cannot be parsed into a number") on all of the example inputs I gave in the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that `VALUE` is the answer to OP's first question and the title too.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei I don't know JavaScript but that isn't how I understood the OP's question.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative that works with cell containing cup or cups

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(INT(LEFT(B1:B2,FIND(" ",B1:B2)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

A `parseInt()` alternative is:

### Formula

```
=INT()
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(INT(LEFT(B1:B2, LEN(B1:B2)-5))))
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Note

The `LEN(B1:B2)-5`, includes a white space.

### Reference

https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093490

Answer (score 2):

Seems a good use for regex. For example:

[image: WA57716 example]

where the formula in E2 is:

```
="="&join("+",ArrayFormula(regexreplace(B2:D2,"\D","")))
```

This strips all non numerics, concatenates the result with `+` and prepends `=`.

Copy/Paste/Paste values only that into, say, F2 (could be E2) then Replace `=` with `=`.

[JOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077)
[REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use RegEx:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"[0-9]+")
```

Use `;` instead of `,` in countries where `,` is the decimal seperator (like in Germany).

Comment: This results in a non-number text output that do not work in formula or sorting. `ISNUMBER()` also returns false on this output

Answer (score 1):

User @6005 's answer was very close, except I needed to parse, for example `3km` and it wouldn't work.  So my solution is just to extract out all the continuous characters that can be part of a number: `digit`, `.`, `-`, and `,`:

```
=VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(A1), "[\d,.-]+"))
```

Examples:

[image]

Note that it is a simple extraction as the regular expression of a valid number with plus and minus sign, thousand separator, decimal, can be quite complicated. See [this post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148034/regex-for-number-with-decimals-and-thousand-separator) and [this post on O'Reilly](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch06s11.html).